# How to convert radio button to single click button

Tags: java, android, button, radio-button, onclicklistener

In my app I have one button for changing theme. And I have 3 different themes. I found a code in github perfect to me but in that code using radio button for changing theme. And i dont wanna use radio button, the user should see different theme evertime he clicked theme button. So i checked internet if there is a sample for converting radio button to clickListener but i couldn't find any.

```
public void showDialog(View view) {
       final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
       dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
       dialog.setCancelable(false);
       dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
       dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

       RadioGroup radioGroup = dialog.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
       Button submitBtn = dialog.findViewById(R.id.submit);
       Button cancelBtn = dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);

       radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int itemChecked) {
               switch (itemChecked) {
                   case R.id.themeBlue:
                       editor.putInt("theme", R.style.BlueTheme);
                       editor.apply();
                       break;
                   case R.id.themeOrange:
                       editor.putInt("theme", R.style.OrangeTheme);
                       editor.apply();
                       break;
                   case R.id.themeGreen:
                       editor.putInt("theme", R.style.DefaultTheme);
                       editor.apply();
                       break;
               }
           }
       });

       submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               dialog.dismiss();
               recreate();
           }
       });

       cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               dialog.cancel();
           }
       });
       dialog.show();
   }
```

This is the code on [github](https://github.com/fari-zma/ThemeSample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/farizma/themesample/RandomTheme.java)

```
        themeButton = findViewById(R.id.themeButton);
        themeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                
            }
        });
```

and this is mine.Can you help me please?

Comment: Why doesn't the setOnChangeListener you have implemented not meet your needs?

Comment: it's meets my needs completely but i don't wanna pop ups in my app. I think if the theme would changes with every single button click the app looks better.

Comment: Radio buttons dont have a pop up,  it sounds like you don't want the dialog window and want display the buttons in a layout

Comment: Yes sorry, when i said pop up i meant dialog. I have sound, vibration and theme button. Sound and vibration buttons are okey. one press opening sound and another close. I wanna same thing with theme too, one press would change theme with no dialog, other press get second theme, third press get third theme. I know it is not hard to do but i don't have experience for it. I tried everything since last night but i got nothing.

Comment: If you dont need the dialog window,  can it be an activity or fragment layout that displays the radio group?

Comment: So you are saying i should definitely use radio grup one way or another.

Comment: For your approach to theme selection, I would use a radio group displayed in a fragment layout.